# Выборка данных из таблицы MySQL за определенный период

Tags: count, дата, php, mysql

Есть таблица с датой в фомате `Y-m-d H:i:s (VARCHAR) "add_date"`
 Там же пишутся `id` пользователей сделавших запись в эту таблицу `"adder_id"`.

Пытаюсь подсчитать через `COUNT()` кол-во уникальных `"adder_id"` в интервале минус час.

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$current_date_hour = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+(-1*60*60) );
```

Пробую и так и так. И через `GROUP BY adder_id`.

Например изначально пытался получить искомое значение через:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM `note_block`
 WHERE `add_date` < '".$current_date."' 
 AND `add_date` > '".$current_date_hour."'
 GROUP BY `adder_id`
```

или

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM `note_block`
 WHERE `add_date` > '".$current_date_hour."'
 GROUP BY `adder_id`
```

Но счетчик выводит что угодно кроме ожидаемой цифры. =(

Comment: Для хранения даты надо использовать типы данных DATETIME или TIMESTAMP ([link][1])

[1]: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html

Comment: В данном примере сути это не меняет. Если убрать условие с датами, все равно показания не те, что ожидаются. Ради чистоты эксперимента привел к DATETIME.

Comment: Функции даты и времени http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ларчик открывался просто...

SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT adder_id) 
FROM `note_block` 
WHERE `add_date` > '".$current_date_hour."'

Comment: Почитайте про `WHERE add_date > add_date + INTERVAL 1 HOUR`

Comment: @ua6xh Das ist fantastisch!

     WHERE add_date > add_date + INTERVAL 1 HOUR

Почему мне кажется, что это условие -- всегда "ложь"? (Быть больше себя, увеличенного на час. Однако)